# How do I optimise a large (not huge) Pandas iterative process via chunking or streaming?

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping to get a few suggestions for the best method for this iterative process I have on a large (~10m rows) pandas dataframe. I am using Python 3.7. The dataframe has a structure like so:

```
           start_time              flag
0 2019-12-01 15:31:42              True
1 2019-12-01 15:32:37             False
2 2019-12-01 15:47:58             False
3 2019-12-02 09:19:13              True
4 2019-12-02 09:21:12             False
5 2019-12-02 09:24:04             False
6 2019-12-02 11:26:31             False
7 2019-12-02 12:10:56             False
8 2019-12-02 12:25:13             False
9 2019-12-02 13:09:25             False
```

What I would like to do is the following:
Every time the flag is true, then assign new columns `start_day` and `start_hour` as the day and hour values from the column `start_time`. Every time the flag is false, then assign `start_day` and `start_hour` to the value in the previous index.

So the desired result is:

```
       start_datetime              flag       start_day      start_hour
0 2019-12-01 15:31:42              True               1              15
1 2019-12-01 15:32:37             False               1              15
2 2019-12-01 15:47:58             False               1              15
3 2019-12-02 09:19:13              True               2               9
4 2019-12-02 09:21:12             False               2               9
5 2019-12-02 09:24:04             False               2               9
6 2019-12-02 11:26:31             False               2               9
7 2019-12-02 12:10:56             False               2               9
8 2019-12-02 12:25:13             False               2               9
9 2019-12-02 13:09:25             False               2               9
```

For additional information, the `flag` column is around 90% False, but the gaps between True values vary significantly.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def startBuilder(df):
    df.loc[df['flag'], 'start_day'] = 1
    df.loc[~df['flag'], 'start_day'] = 0
    df['start_day'] = df['start_day'] * pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_datetime']).day

    df.loc[df['flag'], 'start_hour'] = 1
    df.loc[~df['flag'], 'start_hour'] = 0
    df['start_hour'] = df['start_hour'] * pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_datetime']).hour

    for i, data in df.iterrows():
        if not data['flag']:
            df.at[i, 'start_year'] = df.at[i - 1, 'start_year']
            df.at[i, 'start_month'] = df.at[i - 1, 'start_month']
            df.at[i, 'start_day'] = df.at[i - 1, 'start_day']
            df.at[i, 'start_hour'] = df.at[i - 1, 'start_hour']

    return df
```

Can I stream/chunk this data into this function? If so, what would be the best way?
Can this function be optimised to take advantage of the fact that `flag` is 90% false?

I have tried the following, but it is extremely slow (about 9x slower than the above):

```
def startBuilder2(df):
    df.loc[df['flag'], 'start_day'] = 1
    df.loc[~df['flag'], 'start_day'] = 0
    df['start_day'] = df['start_day'] * pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_datetime']).day

    df.loc[df['flag'], 'start_hour'] = 1
    df.loc[~df['flag'], 'start_hour'] = 0
    df['start_hour'] = df['start_hour'] * pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_datetime']).hour

    idx1 = df[df['flag']].index
    idx_pair = zip(idx1[:-1], idx1[1:])
    for pair in idx_pair:
        df.at[(~df['flag']) & (df['flag'].index.to_series().between(pair[0], pair[1])), 'start_day'] = df.at[pair[0], 'start_day']
        df.at[(~df['flag']) & (df['flag'].index.to_series().between(pair[0], pair[1])), 'start_hour'] = df.at[pair[0], 'start_hour']

    return df
```

Apologies for the huge post, just want to provide as much context as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to chunk.  See if this works for you.

```
df['start_day'] = np.nan
df['start_hour'] = np.nan
mask = df['flag'].eq(True)
df.loc[mask, 'start_day'] = df.loc[mask, 'start_time'].dt.day
df.loc[mask, 'start_hour'] = df.loc[mask, 'start_time'].dt.hour
df.loc[:, ['start_day', 'start_hour']] = df.loc[:, ['start_day', 'start_hour']].ffill()
```

Comment: Awesome - Thanks a lot